# SQL with subqueries, efficient way

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

Is there a better way to get distinct result of ***page_id*** with a condition, where

```
value_id = 1 and filter_id = 2
and
value_id = 25 and filter_id = 3
and
value_id = 144 and filter_id = 443
```

rather than creating sub-queries like so:

```
SELECT
    page_id
FROM
    filter_page_value
WHERE
    value_id = 144
    AND
    filter_id = 443
    AND
    page_id IN
    (
        SELECT
            page_id
        FROM
            filter_page_value
        WHERE
            value_id = 1
            AND
            filter_id = 2
            AND
            page_id IN
            (
                SELECT
                    page_id
                FROM
                    filter_page_value
                WHERE
                    value_id = 25
                    AND
                    filter_id = 3
            )
    )
```

My **filter_page_value** looks like this

```
+---------+----------+-----------+
| page_id | value_id | filter_id |
+---------+----------+-----------+
|    1509 |        1 |         2 |
|    1509 |       25 |         3 |
|    1509 |      144 |       443 |
|    1508 |        1 |         2 |
|    1508 |       25 |         3 |
|    1507 |      484 |       111 |
|    1507 |     1110 |       473 |
+---------+----------+-----------+
```

Comment: I think you mean `OR`, not `AND`, on the between-lines in your initial psuedocode.

Comment: What DBMS (MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle etc.) are you using?

Comment: Can the `value_id/filter_id` pairs be duplicated for a given `page_id`?

Comment: @Dai, nope, I meant AND, this is web e-commerce product filter, where you can choose multiple options.

Comment: @Nick, I am using MySql 8, value_id/filter_id can not be duplicated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can `COUNT` all the occurrences of `value_id, filter_id` pairs that match your desired inputs (`(144, 443),(1, 2), (25, 3)`) for each `page_id` value, and select only those values which match all 3:

```
SELECT page_id
FROM filter_page_value
WHERE (value_id, filter_id) IN ((144, 443), (1, 2), (25, 3))
GROUP BY page_id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 3
```

Output (for your sample data):

```
page_id
1509
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/75BWDCk9QL6XakvaUxJgtr/1)